# How would one implement a multi-agent environment with asynchronous action and rewards per agent?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ai-design, multi-agent-systems

In a single agent environment, the agent takes an action, then observes the next state and reward:

```
for ep in num_episodes:
    action = dqn.select_action(state)
    next_state, reward = env.step(action)
```

Implicitly, the for moving the simulation (env) forward is embedded inside the env.step() function.

Now in the multiagent scenario, agent 1 ($a_1$) has to make a decision at time $t_{1a}$, which will finish at time $t_{2a}$, and agent 2 ($a_2$) makes a decision at time $t_{1b} < t_{1a}$  which is finished at $t_{2b} > t_{2a}$.

**If both of their actions would start and finish at the same time**, then it could easily be implemented as:

```
for ep in num_episodes:
    action1, action2 = dqn.select_action([state1, state2])
    next_state_1, reward_1, next_state_2, reward_2 = env.step([action1, action2])
```

because the env can execute both in parallel, wait till they are done, and then return the next states and rewards. But in the scenario that I described previously, it is not clear how to implement this (at least to me). Here, we need to explicitly track time, a check at any timepoint to see if an agent needs to make a decision, Just to be concrete:

```
for ep in num_episodes:
    for t in total_time:
       action1 = dqn.select_action(state1)
       env.step(action1) # this step might take 5t to complete. 
       as such, the step() function won't return the reward till 5 t later. 
        #In the mean time, agent 2 comes and has to make a decision. its reward and next step won't be observed till 10 t later.
```

To summarize, how would one implement a multiagent environment with asynchronous action/rewards per agents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution from a theoretical point of view is to switch over to a hierarchical framework, some framework that supports temporal abstraction. My favourite one is the [options framework as formalised by Sutton, Precup and Singh](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0004370299000521).

The basic idea is that the things that you consider "actions" for your agents become "options", which are "large actions" that may take more than a single primitive time step. When an agent selects an option, it will go on "auto-pilot" and keep selecting primitive actions at the more primitive, fine-grained timescale as dictated by the last selected option, until that option has actually finished executing. In your case, you could:

- implement the first "primitive action" of an option to immediately apply all effects to the state, and append a sequence of "no-op" actions afterwards to make sure the option actually has a longer duration than a single primitive timestep, OR
- implement the very last primitive action of an option to actually apply changes to the state, and prepend a sequence of "no-op" actions in front of it to make the option take more time, OR
- something in between (i.e. actually make partial changes to the state visible during the execution of the option).

Since **all** legal choices for agents in your scenario appear to be options, i.e. you do not allow agents to select primitive actions at the more fine-grained timescale, you would only have to implement "inter-option" learning in your RL algorithms; there would be no need for "intra-option" learning.

In practice, if you only have a small number of agents and have options that take relatively large amounts of time, you don't have to actually loop through all primitive time-steps. You could, for example, compute the primitive timestamps at which "events" should be executed in advance, and insert these events to be processed into an event-handling queue based on these timestamps. Then you can always just skip through to the next timestamp at which an event needs handling. With "events" I basically mean all timesteps at which something should happen, e.g. timesteps where an option ends and a new option should be selected by one or more agents. Inter-option Reinforcement Learning techniques are basically oblivious to the existence of a more fine-grained timescale, and they only need to operate at precisely these decision points where one option ends and another begins.